# Does anyone know how to set a variable with randInt() on Ti-84 Plus CE?

Tags: ti-basic

I was just messing around writing a slot machine program on my PlusCE and I tried to run this:

:randInt(111,999,1)->A

But it won't save to the variable

Any ideas?

Comment: Drop the third parameter. Three-parameter `randInt` returns a list, which cannot be stored to `A`. Since you only want one result, the two-parameter version should do just fine. [See this](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/randint)

Answer (score 1):

randInt returns a list, even if you only want one trial. So you need to store the result in a *list* variable.